# C++ stringstream segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stringstream

I have writen this program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

double distance(vector<double> *, vector<double> *, int);
const char* distances(vector<vector<double>* >, int);

double distance(vector<double> a, vector<double> b){
    double result = 0, di;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        di = a[i] - b[i];
        result += di*di;
    }
    return sqrt(result);
}

const char* distances(vector<vector<double>* > vectors, int accuracy=1){
    stringstream graphstr;
    graphstr << "strict graph {\n";
    for(int i=0; i<vectors.size();i++){
        int j=i+1;
        while(j<vectors.size()){
            graphstr << "\t" << i << " -- " << j << "\t [len=" << distance(vectors[i],vectors[j]) << "];\n";
            j+=accuracy;
        }
    }
    graphstr << "}\n";
    return graphstr.str().c_str();
}
```

and when the `vectors.size()` is greather than 70 it gives me a segmentation fault. what is the problem?

when I not adding new stings to `graphstr` it is OK.

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings enabled & debug information (i.e. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux)? Then use a debugger (i.e. `gdb` or its `ddd` GUI frontend on Linux) on it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning pointer to the string which gets deallocated at the exit from function.

Comment: For instance, return `std::string` - `graphstr.str()`

Comment: It works! Thank you! I didnt know what is the problem. But i wanted a const char* as returning value, while i make a python extension with swig and swig makes a PyString from a const char*. But I solved     it with a typemap:
    `%typemap(out) (string) {
        $result = PyString_FromString($1.c_str());
}`

Comment: I don't know much about swig, how to approach that depends on how memory is going to be managed later. Hopefully your approach is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change your return value from const char* to char* and

```
 char* buff = new char[4096];
 strcpy(buff,graphstr.str().c_str(),graphstr.str().size());
 return buff;
```

Remember to free the memory returned using delete

Comment: He will forget, I'd recommend changing return type and return string (actually, I *did* recommend it already:))

Comment: I am a honest fellow and wouldn't lie being in immediate danger of discovery ;-)